# Connecting objects

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have $n$ objects, and you want to connect them so that each object is connected to every other object.

How many connections do you need?

I think that  you need $\frac{n!}{2}$ connections.

For every $2$ objects, you have one connection.  Each time you “connect” an object, you already have n connections to that object.  Hence the factorial.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{2}~$ connections.

Each connection is associated with some unique way of selecting $~(2)~$ items from $~(n)~$ items.

The selections are made without replacement, because it is presumed that you don't have an object connect to itself.

The combinations rather than permutations are counted, because connecting A to B is the same as connecting B to A.